# Which of the following integers cannot be expressed as the sum of two prime numbers?

Tags: arithmetic

Please help me with this problem. I'm stumped!

which of the following integers cannot be expressed as the sum of two prime numbers?

A) $8$

B) $9$

C) $10$

D) $11$

E) $12$

According to the GRE book the answer is....
D) $11$

Comment: What did you try? The easiest form, in this case, is check one by one. For example, 8=5+3. Thus (A) is not the answer

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the poster is directly copying an easy test question without the least personal input or effort.

Answer (score 2):

Brute force works well for numbers as small as these. Otherwise it helps to know the following facts

- There is *no* known even number $\ge 4$ that is *not* a sum of two primes. (And all even numbers with 18 or fewer digits have been tested. See [Goldbach's conjecture](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GoldbachConjecture.html)).
- If an *odd* number is the sum of two primes, one of them must be $2$. (In other words an odd number $n$ is the sum of two primes if and only if $n-2$ is prime).

Answer (score 1):

HINT: 
$$
11=1+10=2+9=3+8=4+7=5+6
$$
and there is no other possibility.

Answer (score 0):

The primes less than 12 are 2,3,5,7,11

To get 8:

2+6 (nope); 3 + 5 (yep)  8 = 3+5 is a sum of primes

To get 9:

2+7 = 9.  (yep)

To get 10:

2 + 8 (nope); 3 + 7 (yep) (also 5 + 5) 10=3 + 7 = 5 + 5 is the sum of primes

To get 11:

2 + 9 (nope); 3 + 8 (nope); 5 + 6 (nope); 7 + 4 (nope; we've gone past the halfway point; if we were going to find any sum of primes we would have found it already... but lets keep going); 11 + 0; (nope)  **11 is not the sum of two primes**.

To get 12:

2 + 10(nope); 3 + 9 (nope); 5 + 7 (yep).  12= 5 + 7 is the sum of two primes.